# Database configuration does not specify adapter (Sinatra + Nginx + Activerecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby, sinatra

Здравствуйте.

Делаю деплой на удаленый сервер. При деплое запускаю миграции(cap production deploy:migrate), выдает следующую ошибку:

```
 Command: cd /home/deploy/sudoku/current && ( export RACK_ENV="" ; bundle exec rake db:migrate )
 DEBUG [7fadeecc]   rake aborted!
 DEBUG [7fadeecc]   ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
 DEBUG [7fadeecc]   /home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:170:in `spec'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.11/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:50:in `database='
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1217:in `set'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.11/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:41:in `database_file='
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1217:in `set'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.11/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:22:in `registered'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1400:in `block in register'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1398:in `each'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1398:in `register'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1969:in `register'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2030:in `register'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.11/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:63:in `<module:Sinatra>'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.11/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/sudoku/releases/20161216055930/app.rb:3:in `require'
/home/deploy/sudoku/releases/20161216055930/app.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/sudoku/releases/20161216055930/Rakefile:1:in `require'
/home/deploy/sudoku/releases/20161216055930/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/sudoku/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
 DEBUG [7fadeecc]   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Настройка подключения базы данных:

```
development:
  adapter:   "sqlite3"
  database:  "sudoku_database.sqlite3"  

production:
  adapter:   "sqlite3"
  database:  "../../db/sudoku_database.sqlite3"
```

**deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.4.0'
set :default_env, { 'RACK_ENV' => "production" }
set :application, 'sudoku'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:user/sudoku.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/project'

#set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{ log }


namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  task :migrate do
      on roles(:app) do
        within release_path do
          with rack_env: fetch(:rack_env) do
          execute :rake, "db:migrate"
          end
        end
      end
    end

  #after 'deploy', 'migrate'
  #after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  #after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

На локальном сервере миграции проходят без проблем, создается база данных с соответствующими таблицами.

Comment: `#set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}` закомментирован? Почему? Он есть у вас в репозитории, или только локально?

Comment: есть в репозитории

Comment: А где выполняется `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`?